# Fetch mails from gmail without using "Application Specific Password"

Tags: php, imap, gmail-api

In PHP, I need to fetch mails from gmail without using `Application Specific Password` when 2 step verification is enabled. I already tried fetching mails with `Application Specific Password` using `imap` and its working fine. But I don't want that. I need without using app specific password I should able to fetch mails from gmail.

For example: if you go through **nimble.com**, you can login through google and there they are fetching emails from gmail using login credentials only with or without 2-step verification.

Comment: I think you need to read the API documentation, specifically how to authenticate with OAuth.

Comment: Yes, you need to use OAUTH2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the OAuth 2.0 protocol to authorize the Gmail API. I think the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) is a great way to learn how it works. Just set your scopes to the Gmail API v1 ones to try the Gmail API.

Then you can check out the [PHP client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started) to learn how to use it  in your own application.